# How to design batches in a stateful RNN

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm, rnn

I am using TF Eager to train a stateful RNN (GRU).

I have several variable length time sequences about 1 minute long which I split into windows of length 1s.

In TF Eager, like in Keras, if `stateful=True`, "the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch." ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU))

Thus, how should I design my batches? I obviously cant sample random windows from random sequences. I also cant split a sequence into windows and place adjacent windows in the same batch (e.g. `batch 1 = [[seq1 0-1s], [seq 1 1-2s], [seq1 2-3s], ...]`), as the state from the previous window wont get passed to the next window, as is the point of a stateful RNN.

I was thinking of mixing sequences in the same batch as in:

```
batch 1 = [[seq1 0-1s], [seq2 0-1s], [seq3 0-1s], ...]
batch 2 = [[seq1 1-2s], [seq2 1-2s], [seq3 1-2s], ...]
...
```

However, there the issue is that the sequences have different length, and thus some will finish before others.

So what is the best way to implement this?

(FYI, I couldn't find anything in the academic literature or blogoshhere which discusses this, so refs would be great)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered padding all sequences with silence (all 0‘s) to get the same length? Your approach sounds like it‘s correct.

Comment: I have not. Is that the standard practice? One con would be wasted inference which would lengthen training process

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Your specific case

After `[seq1 0-1s]` (1st sec of long sequence `seq1`) at index `0` of batch `b`, there is `[seq1 1-2s]` (2nd sec of the same sequence `seq1`) at index `0` of batch `b+1`, this is  exactly what is required when we set `stateful=True`.

Note that the samples inside each batch **must be the same length**, if this is done correctly, difference in sequence-length between (not inside) batches causes no problem. That is, when all samples from batch `b` are processed, then next batch `b+1` will be processed, and so on and so forth.

#### A general example

As a general example, for `stateful=True` and `batch_size=2`, a data set like

```
seq1: s11, s12, s13, s14
seq2: s21, s22, s23
seq3: s31, s32, s33, s34, s35
seq4: s41, s42, s43, s44, s45, s46
```

where `sij` denotes j-th time step, must be structured like

```
    batch 1         batch 2         batch 3         batch 4  

0   s21, s22        s23, <pad>      s31, s32, s33   s34, s35, <pad>   ...
1   s11, s12        s13, s14        s41, s42, s43   s44, s45, s46
```

or like (with overlap)

```
    batch 1         batch 2         batch 3         

0   s21, s22        s22, s23        s23, <pad>    ...
1   s11, s12        s12, s13        s13, s14
```

where, for example, long sequence `s21, s22, s23` (3 time steps) is broken down to two sub-sequences `s21, s22` and `s23, <pad>`. Also, as you see, it is possible to have batches with different sequence lengths (by using a [custom batch generator](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/48814/67328)).

Note that `<pad>` (padded values) should be *masked* to prevent RNN from considering them as actual values (more info in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/49168/67328)). We can also avoid using padded values by opting for `batch_size=1` which might be too restrictive (more info in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/48796/67328)).

Here are two examples of a sequence with 5 time steps:

```
            s11   s12   s13   s14   s15

example 1   23,   25,   27,   24,    28     # 5 temperature readings for t to t+4

example 2   I,    like, LSTM, very,  much   # 5 128-dim word embeddings
```

#### Some resources

1. You may find [this article on stateful vs stateless LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stateful-stateless-lstm-time-series-forecasting-python/) helpful. Some quotes from the article:

   > The stateless LSTM with the same configuration may perform better on
   >   this problem than the stateful version.

   and

   > When a large batch size is used, a stateful LSTM can be simulated with
   >   a stateless LSTM.
2. [This blog on Stateful LSTM in Keras by Philippe Remy](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/)
3. Some opinions on [Keras github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7212), like [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7212#issue-240037404).

Comment: Thanks! 2 q's: 
(1) what do you mean when you say the 0'th index of batch 1 is `s11, s12`. Each batch index will only fit 1 second (e.g. only either `s11` or `s12`)? Also, you increase this to 3 samples in batch 3,4 (e.g. `s31 s32 s33`).
(2) What do you mean by `<pad>`? Do you mean place a sample with all 0's? Wouldn't this negatively affect training time?

Comment: @DankMasterDan I have added extra remarks regarding your questions, Hope it helps. Samples inside a batch must be the same length, by using *masking* there would be no wasted training time.

Comment: Esmailian, thnx! You answered my 2nd question, but not my first. Is the 0th sample of batch 1 `s21` or `s22`? I dont see how it can be both? Concretely, if each sample s_ij is shape [5, 128] (as is 128 dim word embedding), batch shape will be [2,5,128]. So how can batch 1 contain s21, s22, s11, and s12?

Comment: @DankMasterDan each `sij` is one time step (e.g. one word with dimension `[1 128]`). A 1-second chunk of 1-minute sequence could be either 1 time-step or N time-steps (N > 1).

Comment: got it. Had a brain fart there for a seconds. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I asked a related question on how to implement this in TensorFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978050/using-tf-dataset-api-to-process-sequences-for-stateful-rnn

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you. Although it was rather harsh to implement this reshaping as a general function. Does Keras not have shaping function for its RNNs?