# Using TF Dataset API to process sequences for stateful RNN

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, lstm, rnn

I am trying to use the TensorFlow (v1.13) Dataset API to save and load long sequences for a stateful RNN.

Basically, lets say I have `n_seq` sequences, each fixed to a length of 120.

I want to load batches to train my stateful RNN according to [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51202/how-to-design-batches-in-a-stateful-rnn/51229#51229), basically:

```
           batch 1         batch 2         batch 3         batch 4  

element0    s21             s22              s23             s24   ...
element1    s11             s12              s13             s14
```

where `sij` denotes j-th window of the i-th sequence. This is done based on how a stateful RNN works in TF, as when `stateful=True`, "the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch." ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU))

#### Initial Solution

I am saving each sequence to its own *.tfrecord file. Then I am loading them using:

```
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path, shuffle=False, seed=1)
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.interleave(
    lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(parse_func),
    cycle_length=BATCH_SIZE,
    block_length=1
)
tf_dataset = tf_dataset.batch(batchsize)
```

This actually mostly works EXCEPT for the final files. Namely if `n_files % BATCH_SIZE != 0`, the finale files will be together in the same batch.

Is there a better way to handle this?

*NOTE:* This question was previously asked on stackoverflow.coom, but deleted due to lack of response. I think this will be a better home for it.